# Why isn't my ternary expression working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add and remove some classes depending on window size.

```
var windowSizing = function() {
    var $toggleClass;
    var $window = $(window);
    var $iconsContainer = $('.fragments-content > .icons-container');
    ($window.width() > 769) ? $iconsContainer.addClass('mob-only') : $iconsContainer.removeClass('mob-only');
    $window.resize(function(event) {
        ($window.width() > 769) ? $iconsContainer.addClass('mob-only') : $iconsContainer.removeClass('mob-only');
    });
};
```

I am playing with `.mob-only` and I want to apply it in a ternary operation.

Is there any other way? What am I missing?

Comment: A ternary is something which produces a value, it is not a statement in of itself. Use `if` or `#classList#toggle`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: try `$iconsContainer.toggleClass('mob-only', $window.width() > 769) `. Also, your ternary operator should work. Can you create a working snippet where we can debug it?

Comment: @Rajesh put this as an answer. It worked :)

Comment: Can you explain "isn't working?" What precisely is the snippet doing and how does that differ from your expectations?

Comment: _"Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var windowSizing = function() {
  var $toggleClass;
  var $window = $(window);
  var $iconsContainer = $('.fragments-content > .icons-container');
  ($window.width() > 500) ? $iconsContainer.addClass('mob-only'): $iconsContainer.removeClass('mob-only');
  $iconsContainer.html($window.width());
  $window.resize(function(event) {
    ($window.width() > 500) ? $iconsContainer.addClass('mob-only'): $iconsContainer.removeClass('mob-only');
    $iconsContainer.html($window.width());

  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  windowSizing();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fragments-content">
  <div class="icons-container">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Your code is fine may be there will be any error in your page please see the code running in fiddle